# Select lines from line margin - mouseDragged event not keeping up with selection processing

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am building a text editor and trying to add the ability to select lines using the line number margin. My current approach is to use mouseDragged to update the selected lines. This works fine when doing slow mouse movements, but when doing faster movements the selection isn't able to keep up and just stops updating.

I have tried using a new thread for the processing of the selected range but it still freezes.

**Update: Changed to a mouse range of two values (min/max) rather than every line - this fixed the issue**

The mouseDragged method

```
private void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event, Mouse mouse) {
    int eventY = event.getY();
    int currentLineNumber = this.getLineNumber(eventY);

    mouse.endRange(currentLineNumber);

    if(mouse.getRange()[0] != mouse.getRange()[1]) {
        this.selectLineRange(mouse);
    } else {
        this.selectLineForOffset(eventY);
    }
}
```

Mouse state

```
private class Mouse {
    int mouseY = -1;
    int[] range = new int[2];

    private void resetMouse(boolean resetBeginLine) {
        this.mouseY = -1;
        this.range = new int[2];
    }

    void endRange(int lineNumber) {
        range[1] = lineNumber;
    }

    void beginRange(int lineNumber) {
        range[0] = lineNumber;
    }

    int[] getRange() {
        return range;
    }

    boolean validRange() {
        return ((range[0] | range[1]) > 0);
    }
}
```

And finally the select line range method

```
private void selectLineRange(Mouse mouse) {
        if (mouse.validRange()) {
            int minLine = Math.min(mouse.getRange()[0], mouse.getRange()[1]);
            int maxLine = Math.max(mouse.getRange()[0], mouse.getRange()[1]);;

            Element root = editor.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();
            int startSelection = root.getElement(minLine).getStartOffset();
            int endSelection = root.getElement(maxLine).getEndOffset();

            //editor.setCaretPosition(mouse.mouseDirection == Direction.UP ? startSelection : endSelection - 1);
            editor.select(startSelection, Math.max(endSelection - 1, 0));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does your editor not scroll? How do you handle the case, when the text needs to scroll, in that case, the mouse is likely to reach a final position. No more move events will come in.

Comment: Not sure about others, but I myself would need a valid [mcve] to understand your code, problem and question.

Comment: @thst The editor does scroll. That is another issue that I need to work on. I haven't figured out how I want to handle this. I know I need a separate thread to continuously update the selection if the mouse is passed the line number margin bounds but I haven't worked out the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having code in the same function that knows both about the concept of a mouse and the concept of a document is a recipe for disaster.  Split your code into multiple functions where each function works at a different level of abstraction.

All you need is to know at which Y the mouse went down, and at which Y the mouse currently is.  From this, you can at any given moment re-calculate the range of selected lines.  First you convert viewport-Y to workspace-Y, then you convert workspace-Y to line-number, and voila, you have each line number.

This: `selectedLineNumbers.add(currentLineNumber);` presumes that you will receive a mouse event on each line.  If you don't, then your list will contain gaps.  And you won't, because mouse events come few and far apart when you are moving the mouse too quickly.  That's why your `selectedLineNumbers` should be a ***range***, (startingLineNumber, endingLineNumber) not a list of distinct line numbers.